# Group by 3 columns: "Each group by expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference"

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I know questions regarding this error message have been asked already, but I couldn't find any that really fit my problem.

I have a table with three columns (A,B,C) containing different values and I need to identify all the identical combination. For example out of "TABLE A" below:

```
| A | B | C |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
```

... I would like too get "TABLE B" below:

```
| A | B | C | count |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |   1   |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |   1   |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |   1   |
```

(I need the last  column "count" with 1 in each row for later usage)

When I try with "group by A,B,C" I get the error mentioned in the title. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

FYI, I don't think it really changes the matter, but "TABLE A" is obtained from an other table: "SOURCE_TABLE", thanks to a query of the type:

```
select (case when ... ),(case when ...),(case when ...) from SOURCE_TABLE
```

and I need to build "TABLE B" with only one query.

Comment: Can you post the exact query you tried?

Comment: You have '1, 2, 3' and '1, 3, 3' in the first table twice and a "count" of "1" for that row in the desired result table.  Is that a mistake, or do you really want "1" after every unique permutation?  If so, it's not much of a count!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am working on SQL Server Management Studio and it is supposed to be 1 in each row, I am not counting anything at this stage. The solution of Sturgus below helped me to solve my issue. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1):

i think what you are after of is using distinct

```
select distinct A,B,C, 1 [count]   -- where 1 is a static value for later use
    from (select ... from  sourcetable) X
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have the right idea.  My guess is that the error is occurring due to an outer reference in your `CASE` statements.  If you wrapped your first query in another query, it may alleviate this issue.  Try:

```
SELECT A, B, C, COUNT(*) AS [UniqueRowCount]
FROM (
    SELECT (case when ... ) AS A, (case when ...) AS B, (case when ...) AS C FROM SOURCE_TABLE
) AS Subquery
GROUP BY A, B, C
```

After re-reading your question, it seems that you're not counting at all, just putting a "1" after each distinct row.  If that's the case, then you can try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C, [Count]
FROM (
    SELECT (case when ... ) AS A, (case when ...) AS B, (case when ...) AS C, 1 AS [Count] FROM SOURCE_TABLE
) AS Subquery
```

Assuming your outer reference exceptions were occurring in only your aggregations, you should also simply try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (case when ... ) AS A, (case when ...) AS B, (case when ...) AS C, 1 AS [Count] FROM SOURCE_TABLE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works like that :)
I am a beginner in SQL, and if you have a minute, I was wondering if you could explain what is exactly the "outer reference" problem?

Comment: @raphael.cardinaux It's a tricky thing to explain.  I believe the concept of why you were getting your error can be explained decently [here](http://sqlmag.com/blog/aggregates-outer-reference).  Also, don't forget to accept the answer.